# FlatList rendering array in the wrong order

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am implementing a Flat List in my React Native App. I query the data from Firebase and obtain an array of objects. Something strange is happening --> The FlatList is only rendering the last items of the whole array, and in such order that I cannot scroll since there is no more data. Example:

I have array with [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

And FlatList will only render, let's say, 4 items. This is what it renders and in this order:

FlatList in phone

```
   4
   3
   2
   1
```

So what happens is that when I scroll down it bugs because there is no more data to render, or maybe some other reason I don't understand.

My code is very simple:

```
        <FlatList
          windowSize={1}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={itemData => {
            let image = {uri: itemData.item.i};
            return (
              <CustomCardsRecipe
                img={image}
                id={itemData.item.id}
                navigate={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('MainRecipe', {
                    recipe: itemData.item,
                  })
                }
                showToastFunction={message => this.showToastFunction(message)}>
                {itemData.item.t}
              </CustomCardsRecipe>
            );
          }}
        />
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I could really use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my style.

I had this:

```
flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
```

By simply removing that line it worked.